# What UI element is best to use to show Terms and Conditions?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface

What is the best UI object to use to display the "Terms and Conditions" to the user in an app? I want to notify the user that they are about to upload some video and data to a server, and make sure they are aware of that and that they accept it.

I thought of using a `UIActionSheet`, but I need to display a lot of text, so that probably won't suit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with a `UIWebView`. After all, it can display gorgeously formatted HTML. In one of the apps I built I made a special `UIViewController` subclass which loads a `UIWebView` with Accept/Deny buttons. As a bonus, you can keep the EULA on your server and make the `UIWebView` load it by its URL.

Comment: Is there any way to detect if the user actually has scrolled down to the end of the document (and read it completely)?

Answer (score 2):

I would present a modal view controller, with a scroll view in it. Inside that scroll view, put a multi-line UILabel or a UITextView (with editing disabled). The UILabel or UITextView should not fill the scroll view. At the bottom of the scroll view, put your Accept and Cancel buttons. The effect here is that the user will see the body of text, but they will have to scroll down to the end to get to the buttons to progress past the screen. This is similar to what Apple does when the iTunes terms of service get updated, and you have to agree to the new terms before you can download any more apps.

If your terms and conditions are very short, i.e. one screenful or less, then you might get away with not even needing the scroll view.

I would present this modal the first time the user gets to the point of uploading data to the server. Then when they accept, save this data to NSUserDefaults or a local .plist file, so that when your user hits this point in the future, you can just check to see that they have previously accepted the agreement, and don't present it again.

If the user refuses to accept the terms and hits cancel then just hide the modal view controller but don't let them progress further in the app. If they do try to proceed, then present the terms and conditions again.

Comment: I wouldn't save the info to a plist. Upload it with a timestamp to the server for lawyers.

Comment: @NickTurner Good point! Although I'm sure if you can prove with the source code that it is not possible to progress past that point without agreeing to the terms and conditions this would also be sufficient. Saving it locally (as well) allows you to bypass this part without needing to query the server.

Answer (score 0):

Go with a two state uiButton, once image a non selected empty checkbox and other state as selected checked check box with a label of terms and conditions. You can display terms and conditions in a uiwebview. Same Terms and Conditions in an inbundle/local html file or remote file to be loaded in webview.